# Webpack launch browser automatically

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Gulp + live reload serves up my content on localhost and (here's what I'm after) **launches the browser automatically at the server url** whenever i run the gulp command (i.e I don't have to click the browser icon and navigate to the url manually). Can this be done in Webpack too?

I've tried a plugin called open-browser-webpack-plugin, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: I don't want to launch a `webpack-dev-server`, so I used `open-browser-webpack-plugin` and could get it to work. (I use real express server, BTW; but it launches faster than `webpack --watch`).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

For webpack version 2.x, you just add `--open` open to the CLI as documented here:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-open

Alternatively, add the following config to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
  open: true
}
```

Comment: one issue I found is it starts to open the link before the files build are finished. It will be better if it opens the link when everything is ready.

Comment: In package.json remove the value of dev in scripts `--open`
It will auto open browser

Comment: @new2cpp will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67647752/5457113) work for you?

Comment: requires to install the package `npm i --save-dev webpack-dev-server`

Answer (score 11):

For those using Node.js (and npm): put the command in the npm start script:

**MAC**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server & open http://localhost:8080/"
  }
```

**WINDOWS**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "start http://localhost:8000/ & webpack-dev-server"
}
```

Thanks to Enzo Ferey for pointing out that the command needs to look different when on Windows.

Comment: The problem is that you don't take into account webpack config. You've hardcoded `http://localhost:8080/` URL and it's not always the case. But as a workaround it might work.

Comment: This is what I do but I find that I have to pkill the server if I Ctrl-C to break out of it. Any way around this?

Comment: @DanNguyen yeah me too. The problem however does not pertain to this particular way of starting the app, it's related to webpack-dev-server in general.

Answer (score 11):

Emelet answer is not false at all, however it won't work in Windows. I do this with:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "start http://localhost:8000/ & webpack-dev-server"
}
```

100% working and you don't have to install any module or plugin.

Answer (score 8):

To launch the browser, one can add `--open` to CLI command as the accepted answer points it out

```
npm start --open
```

or

```
ng serve --open
```

To avoid doing it all the time: there is a simple change to make in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: This looks amazing as it opens the browser just in time after the bundle is loaded and has the simplest syntax. many thanks!

Comment: This is for angular, yes?

Comment: yes it works for angular if you update your package.json

Answer (score 4):

[In a previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322053/webpack-launch-browser-automatically/34386559?noredirect=1#comment63102341_34386559), I noted that the currently accepted answer does work but it has the side effect of spawning a process that needs to be manually killed. I've since figured out the more canonical way of initiating a browser open action without using a separate webpack plugin.

That said, you do need to install a more general npm package: [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open)

Then create a new file at your project folder named `server.js`. Here's a sample implementation (note that it is in ES6):

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('./webpack.config');


const open = require('open');
const port_number = 8080;

let target_entry = 'http://localhost:' + port_number + '/';
config.entry.unshift("webpack-dev-server/client?" + target_entry);

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {contentBase: 'src', hot: true, stats: { colors: true }, publicPath: '/assets/'})
.listen(port_number, 'localhost' , (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Listening at localhost:' + port_number );
  console.log('Opening your system browser...');
  open(target_entry);
});
```

Note that this line:

```
config.entry.unshift("webpack-dev-server/client?" + target_entry);
```

-- Means you can remove the call to `webpack-dev-server/client?...` from `webpack.config.js`, as this `unshift` command will insert the line into `config.entry`...this is a helpful modularization for when you need to set up an app with multiple environments and different entry points.

Finally, in `package.json`, this is what the `start` command should look like: a call to `node` to run `server.js`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
   //...
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently, I'm using the latest webpack version but the configuration still the same and it works for me. Add new attribute `open: true` at your webpack devServer configuration.
It looks like

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ...,
  module: { ... },
  ...
  devServer: {
    ...
    open: true,
    ...
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
directory/folder: package.json

{
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "webpack": "^4.16.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
},
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --watch"
 },
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  }
}
```

This start script will run the dev server, and both automatically open and update (on-save) the web page. This is for WebPack 4.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this has allready been given in the accepted answer. Its the --open that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Ive had success using [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/) with webpack.

In webpack.config.js I include this:

```
var options = {
    port: 9001,
    host: 'localhost',
    server: {
        baseDir: './public'
    },
    ui: {
        port: 9002
    },
    startPath: process.argv[3].substr(2),
}

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
browserSync(['public/**/*.*'],options);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer @thimthez, however BrowserSync looks like a rather big machine to take in to handle such a small thing. Maybe automatic launching of the browser is included, but so are things like "Interaction sync", "UI or CLI control" and "URL History" (according to their homepage). To clarify: Hot loading is not the issue here, just opening the browser automatically and navigating to a specified url when running the "webpack" command. Thanks for helping me clarify the question!

Answer (score 1):

Launch browser automatically and it is also possible to specify a page when opening the browser with webpack 4.

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --open-page index2.html"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest [webpack dev server syntax](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-open) for specifying a different browser rather than the default one is the following:

```
devServer: {
...
  open: {
    app: {
      name: 'google-chrome'
    }
  }
}
```

The name key will vary based on the OS per specification in the [open package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open#user-content-app) app options docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `devServer`

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.base.config.js');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3000,
    hot:true,
    compress: true,
    open:"Chrome",
    openPage:'index.html'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer will work but it will open your browser will even when compiled bundles arent ready, as mentioned in the comments. Following approach solves this problem:

```
    const { WebpackOpenBrowser } = require('webpack-open-browser'); // use any plugin to open browser

    const PORT = 8080;

    devServer: {
      open: false
    }
    
    plugins: [
      ...
      new WebpackOpenBrowser({ url: `http://localhost:${PORT}`}),
    ]
```