# Browser will not Launch on npm start with webpack Related to webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2 and webpack@^4.0.0 Peer Dependency Issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

I am brand new to JavaScript. In an attempt to learn JavaScript, I cloned the webpack-starter project from GitHub (https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter). Then, I ran a `npm install` in the clone folder on my desktop, and then I ran a `npm audit fix` upon seeing a `found 1 low severity vulnerability` message in the Git Bash console. Then, I saw this message, `npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Before investigating the above warning, I ran a `npm start` in PowerShell from the project folder. I received no error messages, but my browser (Chrome) never launched.

[image: Powershell]

Then, I investigated the `npm WARN` message and found this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64733624/9698039, which led me to this, https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2807#issuecomment-734982609, which led me to the decision to downgrade my version of webpack from ^5.10.0 to "webpack": "^4.0.0".

Before downgrading, here was my **package.json**:

```
{
    "name": "webpack-starter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A light foundation for your next frontend project based on webpack.",
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "npm run lint:styles; npm run lint:scripts",
        "lint:styles": "stylelint src",
        "lint:scripts": "eslint src",
        "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js",
        "start": "webpack serve --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter.git"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "webpack",
        "startkit",
        "frontend",
        "es6",
        "javascript",
        "webdev"
    ],
    "author": "webkid.io",
    "license": "MIT",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter/issues"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
        "eslint": "^7.15.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.2",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "stylelint": "^13.8.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
        "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.10.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.4.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "core-js": "^3.8.1"
    }
}
```

And here was my **webpack.config.dev.js**:

```
const Path = require('path');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const StylelintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].chunk.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
    new StylelintPlugin({
      files: Path.join('src', '**/*.s?(a|c)ss'),
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          emitWarning: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap=true', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

To downgrade webpack, I changed `"webpack": "^5.10.0"` to `"webpack": "^4.0.0"` in the package.json and then ran `npm install` from Git Bash again.

Then, I ran `npm start` from PowerShell once again, and once again I see no error message, and I see the `Compiled successfully` message, but once again the browser does not launch. It appears as if the webpack peer dependency issue is unrelated to the failure of browser to launch issue, but I am new to JavaScript and therefore currently unable to make that claim with 100% confidence.

Answer (score 1):

So, I looked around some more and found this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39753225/9698039, so I added `open: true` to `devServer` in the webpack.config.dev.js, resulting in this,

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    open: true
}
```

And that worked! My browser launched. I'm still not sure if I could have used `webpack` without downgrading, but it seems like the browser launch issue is unrelated to the peer dependency issue.